# nodejs hapi single page

Tags: node.js, angularjs, routes, hapi.js

I have a single app site (NodeJS) and I want to migrate from Express to Hapi, what I normally do is serve static files and route everything else to a single page which contains the angularjs app and the angular routing configuration.

```
// Express routing, first the static files
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/public') );

// Second the api routes
app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    res.send( {api: 'response' } )
});

// Finally everything else maps to the single page app:
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./public/html/controllers.index.html')
});
```

In HapiJS I dont know how to replicate the same code (without using express.static middleware),     because:

```
Hapi = require('hapi');
var server =  new Hapi.Server('localhost', 84);

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file('public/html/index.html');
    }
});
```

In the code above, every request no matter what will be mapped to my single page ('public/html/index.html'), but if I do this, then the js, css, jpg & files will be mapped to the same file instead to the scripts, styles and images (a request to '/images/bg.png' will download the single page instead the image file).

I know that if I set up the path '/' to my single page and then '{p*}' to '{directory: {path: '/public'}}' then I will have the behaviour that I need, but theres one catch, if some user copy and paste an specific url (lets say '/account/login') and then hit enter, that route will be mapped in HapiJS and the response will be 'Not Found (404)', angular routing will never be able to respond.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

The key part of the question is:

- Use only HapiJS (no express or other middleware)
- Don't route every angular route (just route everything else not already routed to single page son angular can handle the routing)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this will help you out but your starting code is a bit "odd" for Hapi.js. This is what i use to set up a simple hapi.js SPA.

If you wish to use specific URLS like the Account/Login, you have to direct your path to that specific section.(path: '/account/login')

The difference lies in the fact that i'm pointing to the directory as a whole, incl. the different files, and you simply reply the index.html file. The listing parameter lets you decide if you want to show directory structure or not in your urls. Default is false.

More info here: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files#directory-handler

```html
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Path = require('path');

var server = new Hapi.Server(8080, 'localhost');


server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{path*}',
    handler: {
   directory: {
            path: './public',
            listing: false,
            index: true
        }
    }      
});



server.start(function(){
 console.log('server started');
});
```

Comment: Not really (after almost one yeeear), 

Every 404 request must respond index.html in their content, the only respond other than index.html should be files that actually exists

*The routing of pages is handled by angularjs, if the route does not exist in angular, angular will show the 404 error.

Comment: This does not handle client side routing. Meaning on refresh of a page you will 404..

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the [inert documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#customized-file-response), I solved this by serving everything out of a static directory. Then I added an onPostHandler to return the index file whenever a 404 was about to be returned. You client side router could then send a redirect to an existing 404.html file in the static files directory.

```
// Static Assets
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{param*}',
  handler: {
    directory: {
      path: ['app/static'],
      listing: false,
      index: ['index.html']
    }
  }
});

// return index.html for everything else
server.ext('onPostHandler', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('WORD');
  const response = request.response;
  if (response.isBoom && response.output.statusCode === 404) {
    return reply.file('app/static/index.html');
  }
  return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me. Looks like a workaround for a quite common problematic, so I'm not sure if that's the cleanest solution

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is invalid. As @Al jey said in the comment. Hapi have their own algorithm to sort the routes, please don't follow this answer.**

---

Similar to expressJS, Hapi handle route by order. Just define routes order by priority:

```
server.route(
{    // Angular/API Route
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
         reply( {api: 'response' } )
    }
});

server.route({    // Other assets If you have
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/assets/{param*}',
    handler: {
    directory: {
        path: './assets',
        listing: false,
        index: true
    }
});

server.route({   // Everything else 
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file('public/html/index.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is actually completely false, HapiJS instead handles routes by their specificity, the definition order is completely irrelevant, unfortunately...

Comment: @Al jey, Yes you're right. After I dig around I found that they have their own order as you said. I'm edit the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

i had success with inert like described [here](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files). If you scroll down, you can find the section "Directory handler".

My solution looks like that:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Path = require('path');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ 
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8001 
});

server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: 'public'
      }
    }
  });


  server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have inert as a plugin.

In your server.js (or whatever you named it), configure the relative path to serve static files see below

```js
const server = new Hapi.Server({
  connections: {
    routes: {
      cors: true,
      files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
      }
    },
    router: {
      stripTrailingSlash: true
    }
  }
})
```

then for your route, register a new route plugin like below. This is assuming you entry index.html (for React or Angular) is inside the public directory as configured above

```js
exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  server.route([{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: '.',
        redirectToSlash: true,
        listing: false,
        index: true
      }
    }
  }])
  server.ext('onPostHandler', (req, res) => {
    const response = req.response
    if (response.isBoom && response.output.statusCode >= 404) {
      return res.file('index.html')
    }
    return res.continue()
  })
  next()
}

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'static-route',
  version: '1.0.0'
}
```

Now everytime HapiJS throws a 404 error, the route it is forwarded to your React / Angular App, which can then handle the route if it exists.

Comment: What happen if on top of that, there's an API route? I tried i think now every route, including the API route, would be redirected back.

Comment: This config only handles 404 + errors, so If you have an api, it shouldn't redirect unless your server throws a 404 + error (this includes 500 + errors).

Comment: You can switch the line that checks if the status code is >= 404 to check specifically for only 404 errors like if (response.isBoom && response.output.statusCode === 404). Hope this helps

Comment: hi, unfortunately it doesn't serve up any api route. you can see my example github code here: https://github.com/7seven7lst/hapi-inert-test
or stackoverflow question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866806/hapi-single-page-application-using-inert-plugin-doesnt-serve-up-api-route

Answer (score 0):

For people using Hapi@18 and Inert.

```js
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    routes: {
      files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
      }
    }
  });

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/static/{param?}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: '.',
        redirectToSlash: true,
      }
    }
  });

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{any*}',
    handler: {
      file: 'index.html'
    }
  });
```

Here my `./build` contains all the JS assets and `index.html`. `index.html` requests entrypoint `./build/main.js` as `/static/main.js`. The rest of the scripts are relative to each other.